CompareWith in material-select and @Input
I have compareWith metod
  compareObjects() {
return (o1: any, o2: any) => {
  if (this.displayKey) {
    if (o1 && o2) {
      return o1[this.displayKey] === o2[this.displayKey];
    }
  }
  return o1 === o2;
};

}
And, this.displayKey, what I get from @Input
Problem is, compareWith is triggered before @Input displayKey: string; is passed and value for this.displayKey is always undefined.
I try to setTimeout for compare but doesn't working.
I try use compareData in ngAfterViewCheck, and not working, bcs there I get passed data but compare in mat-select not't working..
Is there any better way to use compareWith when I need passed data in method?
When I use console.log(this.displayKey) in ngOnInit, ngOnChanges, ngOnAfterView etc, I normally get data, only problem is bcs compareWith is triggered before all of this
Thnx
Edit:
Here is html
    <mat-select
        #input
        [(ngModel)]="value"
        type="text"
        matInput
        [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"
        [placeholder]="label"
        [required]="required" (selectionChange)="itemSelected()"
    (keydown.arrowDown)="selectNextOption()"
(openedChange)="searchSelectInput.focus()"
        [compareWith]="compareObjects">
    ...
    </mat-select>

Stackblitz

please share a simple stackblitz where the issue happens

How does your html look like?

@MoxxiManagarm added to question

comparewith SHOULD BE a function, but in mat-select you should use
<mat-select [compareWith]="compareObjects">
  ...
</mat-select> 

See that NEVER can use, althought compareObject return a function
<mat-select [compareWith]="compareObjects()">
  ...
</mat-select> 

So, you can define your function compareObject like
  //see that you use the construction: "variable="
  //yes, you can equal a variable to a function but see how
  //you use [variable] = (args)=>{...}

  compareObjects = (a: any, b: any) => {
    if (!this.key) return false;

    return a[this.key] ? a[this.key] == b[this.key] : false;
  };

You can also use a "setter" in Input to define the function compareObject
  //see that you define the function
  compareObjects = (a: any, b: any) => false;

  @Input('key') set _(value: string) {
    //in "setter" you change the definition of the function

    this.compareObjects = (a: any, b: any) => {
      if (!value) return false;

      return a[value] ? a[value] == b[value] : false;
    };
  }

You can see a little stackblitz

thnx for answer, that part with "<mat-select [compareWith]="compareObjects()">" was mistake in stackblitz, i use it without '()', like I write in my original question. Thnx buddy

I try your solution, but it still has the same problem. Method 'compareObject' tries to get '@Input() displayKey' before it is initialized.

You can initialize the input in the way Input() key="value". IF you check my stackblitz, the second approach (setter) works always, the first one, if you change the "key", you should change the value of the "select" to work.

Thnx to everyone for help, I investigate and found a solution for this problem.
I must execute the compareWith function in the Angular mat-select component only after the @Input() property has been initialized. The issue arises because compareWith might be called before the @Input() value is ready, leading to unexpected behavior.
I create a compareWith function that uses the displayKey after it has been initialized.
And use ngOnChanges to bind the compareWith function only after the @Input() value is available.
 @Input() displayKey?: string;
  compareWithFn: (o1: any, o2: any) => boolean;

  constructor() {
    // Set an initial comparison function used if displayKey is not yet available
    this.compareWithFn = this.defaultCompareWith;
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['displayKey'] && this.displayKey) {
      // When displayKey is available, bind the appropriate compareWith function
      this.compareWithFn = this.compareObjects.bind(this);
    }
  }

  defaultCompareWith(o1: any, o2: any): boolean {
    return o1 === o2;
  }

  compareObjects(o1: any, o2: any): boolean {
    if (this.displayKey && o1 && o2) {
      return o1[this.displayKey] === o2[this.displayKey];
    }
    return o1 === o2;
  }

And in HTML
<mat-select [compareWith]="compareWithFn"> <-- here is HTML change
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food">
      {{ food.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>

I create a variable compareWithFn that will be used as the comparison function in mat-select.
In the constructor, compareWithFn is initially set to defaultCompareWith, which performs a simple reference comparison until the displayKey is set.
When displayKey becomes available (the ngOnChanges lifecycle hook is triggered when the @Input() value changes), I bind the compareObjects function to compareWithFn.
The compareObjects function uses displayKey to compare objects based on the specified key.
I hope this can help someone also

One issue might the the missing return path. If displayName is defined and either o1 or o2 is not, then your function returns nothing.
compareObjects() {
  return (o1: any, o2: any) => {
    if (this.displayKey) {
      if (o1 && o2) {
        return o1[this.displayKey] === o2[this.displayKey];
      }
      // MISSING RETURN PATH HERE
    }
    return o1 === o2;
  };
}


thnx for answer. 'displayKey' what I get from @Input() is undefined in the moment when 'compareWith' is triggered. If I in compareObject function, for testing purpose, hard coded 'return o1.name === o2.name' everything is working fine,  like I expect. My problem is, how to force compareWith to be triggered after '@Input() displayKey' get value. Function is working correct, only problem is this undefined 'displayKey'. In ngOnInit this displayKey is with expected value (console.log(this.displayKey)// 'name') Thnx

UPDATE:
You also need to add the typescript typesafe check (?.) to allow the rendering of the select, else it will give you accessing property of undefined error.

Also you can use a single level function, instead of returning a function.
compareObjects(o1: any, o2: any) {
  if (this.displayKey) {
    if (o1 && o2) {
      return o1?.[this.displayKey] === o2?.[this.displayKey];
    }
  }
  return o1 === o2;
}

You can render the select only if the displayName is present.
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select *ngIf="displayName" [compareWith]="compareObjects">
    @for (food of foods; track food) {
      <mat-option [value]="food.value">{{food.viewValue}}</mat-option>
    }
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

Stackblitz Demo

Actually it would need to be compareObjects() as it is a function returning a function, which could also be the issue the question owner has.

@MoxxiManagarm I updated it to single level function, thanks!

@NarenMurali thnx for answer. 'displayKey' what I get from @Input() is undefined in the moment when 'compareWith' is triggered. If I in compareObject function, for testing purpose, hard coded 'return o1.name === o2.name' everything is working fine,  like I expect. My problem is, how to force compareWith to be triggered after '@Input() displayKey' get value. Thnx

Btw. In ngOnInit and ngOnChanges this displayKey have expected value (console.log(this.displayKey)// 'name')

@Arter Could you share a simple stackblitz where the issue happens. Because I need more data to debug the issue

@NarenMurali https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-child-component-i9qcn1?file=app%2FChildComponent%2Fchildapp.component.ts

@Arter updated my answer!

Naren, not work, you should use compareObject=(o1: any, o2: any)=>{..}

@Eliseo I removed the inner function so no need for closure and arrow function, right?

With all of these solutions, still have the same problem. Method 'compareObject' tries to get '@Input() displayKey' before it is initialized.

@Arter It's ok, if the auto population and selection works fine! why worry about that?

Because this.displayKey is dynamic, in this scenario it is 'name', but it's not always 'name', sometimes is 'title', 'label', etc...
And bcs of undefined value, mat-selection is not preselected with value from backend.
If I hard coded to name, for test compareWith method, its fine and working. That's the reason why I need to get ()input value before compareWith

@Arter When you change the @Input, reset the select to empty, also this code will handle dynamic changing of displayName

You mean to hide it in view or?

@NarenMurali, I forked your stackblitz here, see that not work -in comments I indicate the changes, add the ngModel, and change the value of the options-

@Eliseo and Naren Murali I add the solution in the answer here. Thnx ppl
